# How to have compiler know whether Arduino or ESP8266?

Tags: programming, arduino-ide

I am doing some work for both Arduino Mini Pro and for a NodeMCU style ESP8266 board. Within the Arduino IDE I tell it what board I am compiling for and downloading to.

How do I access which board in my scripts?

Some sections are for one or the other exclusively. Right now I'm using a `#define` at top of the script, but changing this to switch between boards not the best. For example, version control keeps on thinking I'm in a new branch when I'm not.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of macros defined to help you with this:

- `__AVR__` for any board with AVR architecture.
- `ARDUINO_AVR_PRO` for the **Arduino Pro or Pro Mini** selection in the **Tools > Board** menu.
- `ESP8266` for any ESP8266 board.
- `ARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU` for the **NodeMCU 0.9 (ESP-12 Module)** or **NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)** selections in the **Tools > Board** menu.

This allows you to do things like this:

```cpp
#if defined(__AVR__)
// AVR specific code here
#elif defined(ESP8266)
// ESP8266 specific code here
#endif
```